NuxtLink missing base url when try opening page using right click and select "Open link in new tab"
I use a custom base url which look like this in local development: "localhost:3000/MyBaseName/v.3/#".
Using Nuxt component <NuxtLink> for example:
<nuxt-link to="/about">About<nuxt-link/>

Normally when I click the link it will redirect to page
"localhost:3000/MyBaseName/v.3/#/about",
and if i try to open it using right click and select "Open link in new tab" it will work on local but not in the production server. It seem in production server it show like this:
https://myURL/v.2/#/about (missing base url)
instead of this:
https://myURL/mybasename/v.2/#/about

Have you added mybasename as a custombaseURL in your nuxt.config? (https://nuxt.com/docs/api/nuxt-config#baseurl)

yes I have add a custom baseURL. If I add the baseURL in the nuxt.config. whenever I try to use <NuxtLink> it supposedly add the baseURL after the domain name, but not in production server.

UPDATED
it seem I cant find out why this is happening, so my alternate approach is to use
<a href="the-location-of-the-page">

instead of using
<NuxtLink to="the-location-of-the-page">

